# How to search for a file inside Eclipse CVS Repository without doing check out

Tags: eclipse

I am eclipse CVS to checkout the Projects from a Repository location .

When i provided the path to the Eclipse CVS Repository it displayed a list of nearly 50 Projects (In Eclipse CVS Repository View )

I am searching for a Particualr java file , not sure in which project its present exactly  , so my question is that , is it possible to search for a particular java file inside the Eclipse Respository without doing out the check out ??

I am using Windows 7 as Operating System and Eclipse 3.6 version .

Thanks .

Comment: Which file are you looking for?

Comment: Thanks i am looking for a file named EasyOptions.java

Comment: That file isn't part of any project from eclipse.org. Where did you find the name?

Answer (score 2):

**[EDIT]**

There is no way to "grep" a CVS repository remotely.

You will have to checkout the projects or ask a sysadmin to search for the file `EasyOptions.java,v` on the CVS server and tell you the path. The name of the project/CVS modules is part of that path.

If you're looking for a file in an official Eclipse project, you can use Google or [grepcode](http://www.grepcode.com/).

To further narrow the search in Google, you can limit it by site:

```
site:eclipse.org filename
```

Comment: Thank you , where to enter this site:eclipse.org filename in Eclipse CVS Repository view ??

Comment: I didn't get you actually , the code is inside our CVS Repository path , how can google find that ??

Comment: Ah... I read your question "I'm looking for a file from an official Eclipse project." Sorry. Editing...